# Setting up Postgres server on local machine - Windows 10

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgres 14 in local machine(Windows 10), and while installation selected postgres server as well, along with pgadmin and a couple others.

1. However, im not sure whether postgres server is already started on my local machine.
2. I tried using psql, but seems the credentials are incorrect. What is the default username ? Why am i unable to connect ? Screenshots below:
   [image]

Adding batch script below:

```
@echo off
REM Copyright (c) 2012-2020, EnterpriseDB Corporation.  All rights reserved

REM PostgreSQL server psql runner script for Windows

SET server=localhost
SET /P server="Server [%server%]: "

SET database=postgres
SET /P database="Database [%database%]: "

SET port=PG_PORT
SET /P port="Port [%port%]: "

SET username=PG_USERNAME
SET /P username="Username [%username%]: "

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('chcp ^|find /c "932"') do @ SET CLIENTENCODING_JP=%%a
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET PGCLIENTENCODING=SJIS
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET /P PGCLIENTENCODING="Client Encoding [%PGCLIENTENCODING%]: "

REM Run psql
"PG_INSTALLDIR\bin\psql.exe" -h %server% -U %username% -d %database% -p %port%

pause
```

I also get this warning while installing the setup:
[image]

Edit 1: Post reinstallation , i am getting an issue which says connection refused
[image]

Comment: Edit the batch file that launches psql and fix the path(s). This error message is not related to credentials.

Comment: @JGH which paths are we talking about ?

Comment: probably to psql ... but only you can tell what is in your customized batch file

Comment: you mean runpsql.bat?

Comment: yes (or which ever file you are calling)

Comment: added batch script in description

Answer (score 0):

The path to PGSQL is wrong. Either it is saved in the variable `PG_INSTALLDIR`, which means it should be written between `%%`
`%PG_INSTALLDIR%\bin\psql.exe ...`

or it is not and you should write the full path like

`"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\psql.exe" ...`

Comment: The issue is gone after i added environment variables and did a reinstallation